# Numerical solution for a matrix ODE in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, ode

I am trying to solve a Cauchy problem of the type

y'=A(t)*y

being A a time-dependent square matrix, depending on a number of parameters.

What I have done is to define a function (in a separate file, as needed)

```
function timedepf=timedep(time,y,L,t,gamma,Rx,Ry,T)
a=zeros(3*L);
for j=1:L
    a(j,j+1)=-t;
    a(j+1,j)=-t;
    a(L,1)=-t;
    a(1,L)=-t;
    a(L+j,L+j+1)=-t;
    a(L+j+1,L+j)=-t;
    a(L+L,L+1)=-t;
    a(L+1,L+L)=-t;
    a(2*L+j,2*L+j+1)=-t;
    a(2*L+j+1,2*L+j)=-t;
    a(2*L+L,2*L+1)=-t;
    a(2*L+1,2*L+L)=-t;
    a(j,L+j)=Rx*cos(2*pi*time/T)*exp(-1i*gamma*j);
    a(L+j,j)=Rx*cos(2*pi*time/T)*exp(1i*gamma*j);
    a(L+j,2*L+j)=Rx*cos(2*pi*time/T)*exp(-1i*gamma*j);
    a(2*L+j,L+j)=Rx*cos(2*pi*time/T)*exp(1i*gamma*j);
    a(2*L+j,j)=Ry*sin(2*pi*time/T)*exp(-1i*gamma*j);
    a(j,2*L+j)=Ry*sin(2*pi*time/T)*exp(1i*gamma*j);
end
timedepf=a*y;
```

(please, don't care about the actual form of A, it is just a 3*L X 3*L square matrix) and then to call the solver

```
time_span=[0 T];
[time,V]=ode45(@(time,V)timedep(time,V,L,t,gamma,Rx,Ry,T),time_span,V0);
```

where V0 is a suitable 3*L X 3*L initial condition. Then I am getting the errors

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in timedep (line 23)
timedepf=a*y;
Error in @(time,V)timedep(time,V,L,t,gamma,Rx,Ry,T)


Error in odearguments (line 88)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 114)
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Error in Pumping (line 65)
[time,V]=ode45(@(time,V)timedep(time,V,L,t,gamma,Rx,Ry,T),time_span,V0);
```

I cannot find out where I am wrong. Can you please help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you really specifying `V0` as a matrix? Show all of your code so that others can try to replicate your issue (or better, start off with a simpler problem and get that working before tackling this). Please read the documentation for `ode45`. Your initial conditions, and the inputs and outputs to your integration function must be equal length column vectors. If you specify your initial conditions as a 3L-by-3L matrix, it will "columnized" (`V0(:)`) and your state vector will need to be 9L^2 elements, not 3L elements as you currently have in `timedep`.

Comment: I think you are right, the problem is with the dimensions of `a` and `y` in `timedep`. I have two questions:
1) Does `ode45` work just for vectors or also for square matrices?
2) In the case it also works for matrices, how can I tell him that `y` is a matrix? Is not the initial condition sufficient (yes, it is a correctly-dimensioned square matrix)?

Comment: As the documentation states, all of Matlab's ODE solvers only work with vectors. If you have a matrix ODE or want store your states in a matrix or N-D array you'll need transform back and forth such that the inputs and outputs of your integration function are column vectors. However, based on `y` in your first equation, you appear to just have a regular non-autonomous linear ODE and a regular vector state (`A` is a matrix but that doesn't matter).

Comment: Thank you very much! From the first equation, `y` can be a matrix as well, there are no problems with the dimensions...